# Can an Analysis Services ABF file be restored, or converted, to a PBIX?

Tags: powerbi, azure-analysis-services

Is it possible to use Analysis Services to create an ABF backup file and then somehow restore it, or convert it, to a PBIX file? I know that an ABF file only contains data and metadata, but that is all we need. We don't need the visuals etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find in the following documentation the scripts and methods to restore abf's to datasets. It is a Premium (PPU, per capacity or embedded) option : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-backup-restore-dataset

A new capability will be given by the product group to migrate your Analysis Services directly to Power BI through the portal : https://mybuild.microsoft.com/sessions/c5a57757-aee3-41f4-b03b-6fc94c56a4ed

You are able to restore to a dataset, but you won't be able to convert to pbix directly.

Script :

[image]

Place :

[image]

Output :

[image]

Comment: Is the BackupRestore image you included in your answer part of the new functionality that is coming later? I don't see it in my PBI Services tenant.

Comment: BackupRestore is the name of my workspace, it is a general availability content, in a PPU workspace. I don't have access to the new functionality either

Comment: Ok. I think the gist of all this is that I can restore an ABF file back to our Premium workspace but I cannot convert the ABF directly to PBIX. I would need to download the dataset from the workspace. Is this pretty much correct? The reason I want to convert the ABF to a PBIX is because, for some reason, none of us are able to download the  dataset in question. It will process for several minutes and then error out with no helpful error message.

Comment: Unfortunately, once you have uploaded your dataset without going with Power BI (here, with the XMLA endpoint) you won't be able to download the pbix. Your only option is to modify it using tabular editor, or classic visual studio.

For your error, try to check with large datasets, xmla endpoint or incremental refresh. it blocks downloading from the portal.

Comment: One more question, if I could. You said to check with "xmla endpoint". What exactly would I be checking for? Everything in the PBI service has an xmla endpoint, correct?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. these are three reasons why you can't download a pbix, maybe it is because you used one of it.